# find all polynomials that satisfy $(x-16)P(2x)=16(x-1)P(x)$

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

find all polynomials that satisfy this functional equation
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\ (x-16)P(2x)=16(x-1)P(x)$$

I write the polynomial
$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$
but I found by comparing the LHS ans RHS (after rearrangement) that all coefficients must be zero, except the fourth coefficient; $P(x)=a x^4$.
But when I re-substitute it into the equation I found that it's inconsistent but it make sense only if $a=0$.

Comment: how do you "decompose" the polynomial?

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you please explain how you deduce that $P(x)$ must be $ax^4$?

Comment: @lulu  please re-read the question i modified it

Comment: I have posted something below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the brute force and write
$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\, x^k$$
$$ (x-16)P(2x)-16(x-1)P(x)=0$$
and solve for one sigle $a_k$ at the time, you will have succesively
$$a_1=-\frac{15 a_0}{16}\qquad a_2=\frac{35 a_0}{128}\qquad a_3=-\frac{15 a_0}{512}\qquad a_4=\frac{a_0}{1024}$$ and, for $k>4$, $a_k=0$.

So
$$P(x)=a_0\left(1-\frac{15 x}{16}+\frac{35 x^2}{128}-\frac{15
   x^3}{512}+\frac{x^4}{1024} \right)$$ that is to say
$$P(x)=\frac{a_0}{1024}(x-16) (x-8) (x-4) (x-2)$$

Comment: why you didn't  make $a_0=0$ , cause that's what i did because i thought that it has to be $0$

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to see that the only constant solution is $0$.  Now suppose that $P(x)$ is not a constant.  We remark that, if $P(x)$ is a solution, so is $cP(x)$ for any constant $c$ so we may suppose that the leading term of $P(x)$ is $x^n$ for some $n$.  Comparing the leading terms on the two sides we see that $n=4$.

Letting $x=1$ or $x=16$ shows us that $$P(2)=0=P(16)$$  Letting $x=2$ tells us that $P(4)=0$ and letting $x=4$ then tells us that $P(8)=0$.  It then follows that the only candidate for a monic quartic solution would be $$P(x)=(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)(x-16)$$

It is now a simple matter to confirm that this polynomial does satisfy the functional equation, so the general solution is $$P(x)=c(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)(x-16)$$
for some constant $c$.

Comment: ok thank you i wanted to know if there is any non trivial solutions that i've found but there isn't so thank you

Answer (score 2):

By plugging in $x=16$, we find $P(16)=0$. So $P$ has some positive roots. If $P$ is not $\equiv 0$, it has a *minimal* positive root $x_0$.
Plug in $\frac 12x_0$ to find $0=16(\frac12x_0-1)P(\frac12x_0)$ and so $x_0=2$ as $P(\frac12x_0)\ne 0$. By plugging in $x=2$, we then find $P(4)=0$, next $P(8)=0$ and $P(16)=0$. Similar to above, we find that the maximal positive root is $16$.
So
$$P(x)=(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)(x-16)Q(x) $$
and therefore
$$ (x-16)P(2x)=(x-16)(2x-2)(2x-4)(2x-8)(2x-16)Q(2x)=16(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)(x-16)Q(2x)$$
whereas
$$ 16(x-1)P(x)=16(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)(x-16)Q(x).$$
Therefore $Q(2x)=Q(x)$ for all $x$ (except possibly for $x=1,2,4,8,16$). Hence $Q$ is bounded, hence constant.

Comment: so what is the final answer ? is there any non trivial solutions?

Comment: @El-Mo Plug constant $Q$ into my first display equation ...